# does the java option -XX:+UseCondCardMark work in jdk17?

Tags: java, java-7

I've seen some discussion but I don't see any documentation on the Oracle website.

Some other stackoverflow pages mentioned this.  So I tried it but I didn't get much results (yet).

So I looked for documentation and found none.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

There is no mention of its removal in the changelog and [Cassandra uses `-XX:+UseCondCardMark` with Java 1.7](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/conf/cassandra-env.sh#L211) (albeit only for 64bit JVMs) so I would say it's safe to say it still exists. Typically used and useful on high volume applications, so you may not be able to see a difference with low load testing.

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed in detail at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6190

UseCondCardMark works in server, but not in client (since 7u40, with the Oracle JVM). The JVM will default to client if it is 32 bit, and (has a single core, or less than 2GB ram):

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
```

For older than 7u40, the flag was a no-op in client mode.